# Quickest way of finding the index of an integer vector in a matrix in R

Tags: performance, r, vector, comparison, integer

I have the following problem in R (for a Markov chain). Suppose there is a statespace matrix S with rows of unique integer vectors (states). I am given a vector s from this matrix, and want to determine the index of the row that corresponds to this vector. There are a couple of solutions:

1. A solution using `all.equal` as in:

   ```
   which(apply(S,1,function(x){ isTRUE(all.equal(s,x)) }) )
   ```
2. Map the vectors to a unique string and identify them with this string:

   ```
   statecodes <- apply(S,1,function(x) paste(x,collapse=" ") ) 
   check.equal <- function(s) {
       z <- which(statecodes == paste(s, collapse=" "))
       return(z)
   }
   check.equal(s)
   ```

The first (often suggested) solution is downright terrible; it already takes 2.16 seconds for a state space of 16,000 vectors with length 4. The second solution is a lot faster, taking 0-0.01 seconds for the same state space. However, when the length of the vectors increases, it becomes increasingly slow. I feel that my string method is reasonable, but there must be something better. What would be a quicker way to make such comparisons?

For completeness sake, the state space for my problem could be generated as follows.
If the vector has N elements, and I denotes the maximum that each element of a vector can attain (for example, 10) it is given by:

```
I <- rep(10,N)
S <- as.matrix(expand.grid( lapply(1:N, function(i) { 0:I[i]}) ) )
```

How can the integrality of the states be exploited in order to make an as quick as possible comparison?

Comment: In your second solution, does the time it takes for the creation of the statecodes matter?  That is, if you're doing lots of tests for each statespace, that part only needs to be done once and so could be slower.  But if you're only doing only one test for each statespace, it needs to be done for each test anyway.  The preferred solution is probably different depending on which condition you have.

Comment: I do these comparisons repeatedly, multiple times for each vector in the statespace matrix. Hence, the creation time for a vector of statecodes is not very important. I'm sacrificing a bit of time first, to be better off later on. Perhaps I should've mentioned that. So I'm looking for something that makes for the quickest possible search, disregarding the time for precomputations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way of getting an integer value for each state is to cast the value to an integer and then multiply each column by the right base.

My version of that is `makecheck2`; the version using `paste` is `makecheck2`.  I've also modified the `paste` version to use `match` so it can check multiple values at the same time.  Both versions now return a function to be used to get the match.

The setup for my version is faster; 0.065 sec vs 1.552 sec.

```
N <- 5
I <- rep(10,N)
S <- as.matrix(expand.grid( lapply(1:N, function(i) { 0:I[i]}) ) )
system.time(f1 <- makecheck1(S))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.547   0.000   1.552 
system.time(f2 <- makecheck2(S))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.063   0.000   0.065
```

Here I test with 1 to 10000 values to check.  The `paste` version is faster for small values; my version is faster for large values.

```
> set.seed(5)
> k <- lapply(0:4, function(idx) sample(1:nrow(S), 10^idx))
> s <- lapply(k, function(idx) S[idx,])
> t1 <- sapply(s, function(x) unname(system.time(for(i in 1:100) f1(x))[1]))
> t2 <- sapply(s, function(x) unname(system.time(for(i in 1:100) f2(x))[1]))
> data.frame(n=10^(0:4), time1=t1, time2=t2)
      n time1 time2
1     1 0.761 1.512
2    10 0.772 1.523
3   100 0.857 1.552
4  1000 1.592 1.547
5 10000 9.651 1.848
```

Code for both versions follow:

```
makecheck2 <- function(m) {
  codes <- vector("list", length=ncol(m))
  top <- vector("integer", length=ncol(m)+1)
  top[1L] <- 1L
  for(idx in 1:ncol(m)) {
    codes[[idx]] <- unique(m[,idx])
    top[idx+1L] <- top[idx]*length(codes[[idx]])
  }
  getcode <- function(x) {
    out <- 0L
    for(idx in 1:length(codes)) {
      out <- out + top[idx]*match(x[,idx], codes[[idx]])
    }
    out
  }
  key <- getcode(m)
  f <- function(x) {
    if(!is.matrix(x)) {
      x <- matrix(x, ncol=length(codes))
    }
    match(getcode(x), key)
  }
  rm(m) # perhaps there's a better way to remove these from the closure???
  rm(idx)
  f
}

makecheck1 <- function(m) {
  n <- ncol(m)
  statecodes <- apply(m,1,function(x) paste(x,collapse=" ") )
  rm(m)
  function(x) {
    if(!is.matrix(x)) {
      x <- matrix(x, ncol=n)
    }
    x <- apply(x, 1, paste, collapse=" ")
    match(x, statecodes)
  }
}
```

Comment: PS. If your values are (smallish) integers and can be easily made non-negative this can be sped up because `match`ing with the unique values is then unnecessary. (where smallish may be necessary to avoid overflow)

Comment: PPS.  Also, please check my math.  I have a hunch I should have subtracted the result from match by one before multiplying by the base.

Comment: Also, I think this is basically what the link in the comments to @danas.zuokas's answer is doing.

Comment: Very helpful! I'll have a more thorough look at it tomorrow, but this seems to be just the thing I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, this works well! For single comparisons, `which` beats `match` by far, by the way, but for multiple `match` is faster. I'll have to rewrite my code a bit to make multiple comparisons. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is `which(colSums(abs(t(S)-V))==0)` where `V` is a vector you are looking for.

Comment: Shouldn't `V` be replaced with `matrix(V, nrow(S), ncol(S), byrow = TRUE)`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It works, but it seems to be slower than mapping vectors into a unique identifier (my 2nd method). I was thinking more of translating a vector into a unique integer, but don't know how yet. This comparison has to be done repeatedly, so it should be very fast and preferably not too memory intensive.

Comment: Wow. Your solution is about six times faster. I wonder if it can be done faster.

Comment: Repeated both 1000 times for a 572392x6 matrix. Yours: 91.61 seconds, mine: 10.35 seconds. It's also a lot more memory intensitive to do all those vector operations on such a large matrix. I got some ideas though, but that requires the output to be a numeric value rather than a string. In other words: I need a better mapping.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something,  `sum(abs(X-Y))==0` is necessary but not sufficient.  It's essentially a weak checksum.  If you want each element of X to be equal to its corresponding element in Y, you need to check every element pair. An alternative is to use the equivalent of FEC (forward error correction) encoding methods to achieve high probability of full pattern match.

Comment: sum(abs(X-Y)) can only be 0 when all elements of X and Y are equal; the absolute value is taken elementwise.

Comment: I managed to get some performance advantage by tweaking your code `statecodes <- apply(S,1,function(x)as.numeric(paste(x, collapse="")))` and same for `s`.

Comment: I have thought of this too. Unfortunately, your suggestion will not give a unique solution when the maximum number per vector is higher than 10. Moreover, when there are negative numbers, which is the case in my problem, you cannot translate them one to one to a numeric value as you did. I do know that the negative value does not exceed -1, though.

Comment: edit: that was the main reason for me to include the space, to ensure uniqueness. As an example, consider the vector (11,1) and (1,11) which would both be represented as 111.

Comment: maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102547/is-there-a-bijective-function-which-maps-an-integer-vector-onto-a-single-number) could help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Danas. The link seems very promising. Going to study it more elaborately in the next days, and see whether I can improve the running times by a factor 10 with some other smart techniques. Examples include partitioning the matrix into several smaller matrices, and perhaps by exploiting the structure of a sorted vector of "state codes".